не запускается бот
я хочу сделать бота, но когда я пытаюсь запустить бота он выдает ошибку:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '%7786739667'

изначально я думал что я что то не так сделал, но я перепроверил код на сайте и все так
вот сам код:
import telebot


bot = telebot.TeleBot('%токен%')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_massages(massage):
    if massage.text == 'Привет':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Привет, как ты меня нашел?')
    elif massage.text == '/help':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Напиши привет }:)')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Я тебя не понимаю. Напиши /help.")


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)

(бот если что для телеграмма)
надеюсь на помощь
Изменено: Я все делал через терминал IDE
я делал так:
1)cd \
2)cd путь к боту
3)python bot.py(бот заменял на имя файла)

Изменено 2:вот полная строчка ошибки
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 4, in <module>
    bot = telebot.TeleBot('%7786739667:остальной_токен%')
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 198, in __init__
    self.bot_id: Union[int, None] = util.extract_bot_id(self.token) # subject to change in future, unspecified
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 706, in extract_bot_id
    return int(token.split(':')[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '%7786739667'

Изменено 3: спасибо @CrazyElf и Revolucion for Monica. Но появилась новая ошибка
она выглядит вот так
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 17, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1198, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1273, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1235, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 150, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 93, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 8945, in _run_middlewares_and_handler
    result = handler['function'](message)
  File "bot.py", line 14, in get_text_massages
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Я тебя не понимаю. Напиши /help.")
NameError: name 'message' is not defined

В общем вот так
(я опять же сверялся с кодом на сайте все также)
Изменено 5: Все с прошлым изменением вопросов нет

Одна строка с ошибкой не даёт понять, где именно произошла ошибка. Приведите полный трейс ошибки в вопросе. Там много строк должно быть с диагностикой ошибки, вот прямо их все скопируйте в вопрос. Без этого невозможно сказать, откуда такая ошибка.

@CrazyElf Изменил. Можете прочитать в последнем изменении

Там у вас реальный токен опять. Я его частично убрал. )  Но зато понятно, что там у вас лишние знаки %. Уберите их сначала и в конце. Токен должен быть без этих знаков, как в ответе уже написали.

Понятно спасибо. И спасибо что убрали остальной токен

Все, кто захочет угнать вашего бота, уже взяли токен из истории изменений вопроса

а если удалить бота из базы BotFather'а?

@An9r3z1k Ну в любом случае лучше новый токен завести, я не знаю, как это делается.

я уже завел спасибо всем кто помогал

Блин, ну хоть слова мышкой даблкликать научись в ide? По-твоему massage и message - это одно и то же?


ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '%7786739667'

Эта ошибка обычно возникает, когда в коде что-то пытается преобразовать строку, которая не является числом, в целое число.
Обратите внимание на строку:
bot = telebot.TeleBot('%токен%')

Замените %токен% на ваш настоящий токен без знаков процента вокруг, например:
bot = telebot.TeleBot('123456789:ABCDEF12345ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')

